# Use InStr Function inside Formula R1C1 property

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
splitStr= "_"
```

i am trying to use

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[34]C, InStr(1, R[34]C," & splitStr & "), 10)"
```

but when used in excel, it says `#NAME`?

Please guide me if InStr can be used like this or not?

Comment: No. `InStr` is VBA. You're looking for FIND or SEARCH.

Comment: Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[34]C, Find(" & splitStr & ", R[34]C, 1)+1, 10)"
in that case this is also not working

Comment: `Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(R[34]C, Find(" & splitStr & ", R[34]C)+1, 10)"`

Comment: still not worked, 
i solved it with Chr(34)
Thank you